# Smooth subvarieties through a singular point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a singular variety of dimension $n$, with singular locus of dimension $a$.  Does there always exist a smooth subvariety $V$ of given dimension $m$ (where $a < m < n$) which contains $Sing(X)$?  Of course it is sometimes possible: for example the ruling of a singular quadric cone passes through the singular point.  But I am not sure what the general situation is.

What is the obstruction to finding a $V$?  If there always is a $V$, can you do better, for example by requiring the tangent space to $V$ at a given singular point to contain a particular tangent direction?

Comment: What if $a = n-1$ and $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$ is itself singular?

Comment: If $a = n-1$ then there is no $m$ with $a < m < n$.  But anyway, assume $a = 0$ if you want; I'm curious about any results with this general flavor.  Given a specific $X$ and $m$, how can I tell which way things go?

Comment: Oh, $m$ is given? That is not clear from the current formulation of the question. Please edit the question to clarify your exact assumptions.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are counterexamples with $n=2$, $a=0$ and $m=1$.

Comment: Do you know what the obstruction is in that case?  Given a normal surface singularity, what do I need to compute to know whether there exists a smooth curve passing through it?

Comment: For a normal surface singularity, whether or not the exceptional divisor in some resolution has a reduced component is probably the relevant condition.

Comment: One obstruction is the following: if $X$ is factorial with $p \in X$ a singular point, then any codimension-1 subvariety of $X$ containing $p$ must be singular at $p$.

Comment: If $X$ is factorial, then every codimension $1$ subvariety passing through a singular point is singular itself, so this tells you that on such an $X$ the answer is negative for $m=n-1$.

Comment: ps: Uh, I've just noticed that the same condition was mentioned by @Pop, except that mathoverflow hides comments after a certain number, so you won't see it unless you click on "Show more"...

Comment: @SándorKovács: nice to receive your _imprimatur_. :)

Comment: A simplest example of a normal factorial surface singularity is $E_8$ with equation $x^2 + y^3 + z^5 = 0$. By comments of Pop and Sándor Kovács, there will be no smooth curves on this surface passing through the origin.